# Asymptotic notation from running time

Tags: algorithm, methods, substitution, notation

If I have an algorithm with the running time `T(n) = 5n^4/100000 + n^3/100`, I know that I get `Θ(n^4)`.

Now, if I have something like `T(n) = (10n^2 + 20n^4 + 100n^3)/(n^4)`, does this yield `Θ(n^3)`?

I am trying to eliminate low-order terms to use the Substitution method to prove this.

Comment: Is this a Maths question?

Comment: Are you sure that it's `Θ(n^3)`? For me it's `Θ(n^4)` (first case)

Comment: As the divisor is n^4 the out put will remain as Θ(n^3)

Comment: Second case - yes. but first case?

Comment: Yes, that is my reasoning behind deciding that it must be Θ(n^3) since the n^4 "cancels out"

Comment: What is "cancel out"? Big-theta means that it's both big-O and big-Omega of function. And `5n^4/100000 + n^3/100` is __not__ `O(n^3)`, it's `O(n^4)`. So first case for me is `Θ(n^4)`

Comment: oops, yes the first case should be Θ(n^4). can you elaborate on the second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big-Theta means, that growth is both *big-O* and *big-Omega*.

So first case in your question is `Θ(n^4)`, not `Θ(n^3)` since `5n^4/100000 + n^3/100` belongs to `O(n^4)` and not `O(n^3)`.

Second case:

[image]

Thus, it's `Θ(1)` - because result is `O(1)` and `Ω(1)`: all members, except `20` (constant) will limit to zero when `n` is growing.